# give motion to grass field in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

i have created a grass field which is a combination of several small 60x36 images.a grass object is introduced and then drawn on the canvas.now i want to give it motion .the continuous scrolling effect .i made a code for it and it isn't working( **the images (the grass field)are not scrolling along the width of the canvas which is the goal of this script**).i haven't work much with oop in js. a little discussion on the mistakes i have done will be great

(the image i have used is added to the post)

[image]

```
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
<script>
function makeit(){
var canvas=document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
var height=500-36;
var xpos=[];
var img=new Image();
img.src="grass.jpg";
drawcanvas();
function drawcanvas(){
canvas.width=600;
canvas.height=500;
canvas.style.border="1px solid black";
}
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
xpos.push(i*60);

}

var grass=function(x,y){
this.x=x;
this.y=y;
this.img=img;
ctx.drawImage(this.img,this.x,this.y);

}
grass.prototype.motion=function(){
for(i=0;i<xpos.length;i++){
xpos[i]--;
if(xpos[i]<=-60){
xpos[i]=canvas.width;
}
 ctx.drawImage(this.img,this.x,this.y);
}
}

for(i=0;i<xpos.length;i++){

var grass1=new grass(xpos[i],height);

}
var m=setTimeout(function(){
for(i=0;i<xpos.length;i++){
grass1.motion();
}
},1000);


}
window.onload=makeit;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

actual canvas after drawing all the images

[image]

Comment: Please define "isn't working". You need to give potential answerers as much help as possible!

Answer (score 1):

In essence, all you need is to create an image pattern then translate and draw it to screen.

An example assuming image has been loaded:

```
var ph = img.height;                                // pattern height
var w = canvas.width;                               // width of canvas/scoll area
var h = canvas.height;                              // used to calculate y pos.
var x = 0;                                          // scroll position
ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat-x'); // pattern
```

Then in the loop scrolling the grass:

```
function scroll() {

    ctx.translate(x, h - ph);      // translate to next position
    ctx.fillRect(-x, 0, w, ph);    // fill rectangle (fillstyle = pattern)
    ctx.translate(-x, -(h -ph));   // translate back for other operations

    x--;                           // scroll speed (here 1 pixel / frame)

    requestAnimationFrame(scroll); // loop
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/7J7MM/)**

Pattern fills are anchored to the coordinate system which is why the translate is necessary. As we translate we also compensate for it using draw position in the opposite direction. This will make the pattern be *filled* into the same position but at a variable offset which creates the animation effect.

Just note that if you change fillStyle you need to store the pattern in a variable and reinitialize the fill style. If the loop is long-running also limit x so it doesn't overflow. This can be done using `w` as a condition (or modulo) to reset x to 0.

Comment: it works fine .actually i wanted to create the object and then animate.infact main objective was to learn oop.thanks anyway :)